# Troubleshooting undefined $userId variable in Laravel view

Tags: php, laravel, syntax-error, laravel-livewire

In my view, why is the variable `$userId` undefined inside the button? I tried to make a print layout of absent history, but I need help finding this error.

```
<a href="{{ route('attendance.print', ['user' => $userId]) }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
    <x-tabler-download class="icon-4 mr-1"/>
    <span>Download rekap</span>`
</a>
```

**Route**

```
Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::middleware('can:attendance.index')->get('/attendance', \App\Livewire\Pages\Attendance\Index::class)->name('attendance.index');
    Route::middleware('can:attendance.mine')->get('/attendance/mine', \App\Livewire\Pages\Attendance\Mine::class)->name('attendance.mine');
    Route::middleware('can:attendance.print')->get('/attendance/printAttendance/{user}', \App\Livewire\Pages\Attendance\PrintAttendance::class)->name('attendance.print');
});
```

**Controller**

```
class PrintAttendance extends Component
{
    public $userId;
    public $attendances;

    public function mount($user)
    {
        $this->userId = $user;
        $this->loadAttendances();
    }

    public function loadAttendances()
    {
        $this->attendances = Attendance::where('user_id', $this->userId)->where('approved', 1)->get();
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.pages.attendance.print-attendance', ['userId' => $this->userId,]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you expect `$userId` to come from?

Comment: @TimRoberts From `public $userId`; this is how Livewire works.

Comment: That just makes it a member of the `PrintAttendance` object.  Is it supposed to come from the parameter to `view`?

Comment: @TimRoberts Yes, Livewire works that way. Public properties of a Livewire component are automatically shared with the view (and JavaScript front-end). https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/properties